# linear regression with compositional explanatory variables

Tags: r, glm

I have a data set with a continuous outcome and 24 explanatory covariates. These 24 covariates are added up to 1 (compositional). I'm wondering what special considerations should be placed during building a regression model. I think the regular one is not fully arguable.

A simple example of my dataset is such like that:

```
    y x1 x2 x3
    1.5 0.2 0.3 0.5
    1.2 0.1 0.3 0.6
...
```

Where `X1+X2+X3=1`and I would like a model of y~x1+x2+x3

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about statistical modeling rather than programming. Try crossvalidated.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove any one of the variables and perform standard linear regression. The reason is that given *n-1* variables, you can uniquely determine your *n*<sup>th</sup> variable. Thus, the *n*<sup>th</sup> variable is not required.